# $route.reload not updating service data

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, routes

I am very much new to AngularJS.
Generally I have seen people using `$route` for refreshing data from database. But for learning purpose I have created an object in the custom service, stored some data in the Object and calling that service in the controller.


But when I am adding more values in the object and try to update it using the ngClick, no changes take place. Though, on refreshing the whole page, changes takes place. But I just want that particular section to update. 

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
var app=angular
        .module('app',['ngRoute'])
        .service('data', function(){

            this.students=[
            {id: 1, name: 'Mark', gender: 'Male', city: 'London'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Henry', gender: 'Male', city: 'Manchester'},
            {id: 3, name: 'John', gender: 'Male', city: 'Chennai'},
            {id: 4, name: 'Sara', gender: 'Female', city: 'Sydney'},
            {id: 5, name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', city: 'New York'},
            {id: 6, name: 'Pam', gender: 'Male', city: 'Los Angeles'},
            {id: 7, name: 'Catherine', gender: 'Female', city: 'Chicago'},
            {id: 8, name: 'Mary', gender: 'Female', city: 'Houston'},
            {id: 9, name: 'Mike', gender: 'Male', city: 'Phoenix'},
            {id: 10, name: 'Rosie', gender: 'Female', city: 'Manchester'},
            {id: 11, name: 'Sasha', gender: 'Female', city: 'Hyderabad'},
            {id: 12, name: 'Naatasha', gender: 'Female', city: 'Bhungi'},
            // {id: 13, name: 'akash', gender: 'Male', city: 'lugi'},
            // {id: 14, name: 'aaakash', gender: 'Male', city: 'lugi'}
            ];

        })

        .controller('studentcontroller',function($scope,data,$route){
            $scope.rdata=function(){
                console.log("asd");
                $route.reload();
            };  

            $scope.students=data.students;

        });
```

Here's the code calling it

```
<h1>List of Students</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="student in students">
        <a href="students/{{student.id}}">{{student.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="rdata()">Reload Data</button>
```

Please help me in learning something new.

Comment: `$route.reload();` reloads only current state not an entire app, but service loads only once at the time of initialization of app.

Comment: you can use `$scope.$watch` for updating the data.

Comment: how are you adding data to service?

Comment: simply push the data into the array you don't need to even reload as it is not a good practise

Comment: @RahulSharma sir, all the values are hard coded. I am not adding it from somewhere else.

Comment: @Steve correct me if Im wrong your data is hard coded ? and your pushing data in the students list ? so if you reload your state/route your added data will be gone its because your not saving it in a database.

Comment: @Priz, data is hard coded, and data doesn't goes anywhere. If I reload the page, the data, if pushed, shows up and if removed , disappears from the screen after reload.